# Hue histogram example opencv

Tags: opencv

I have already tried to search here at SO and found many replies but still i am unable to locate my problem.

I am trying to create a Hue-histogram from a color image. My code is following:

```
    Mat input = imread("jan31/class4Jan31.jpg",1);

    Mat hsv_input;

    cvtColor( input, hsv_input, CV_BGR2HSV );

    int h_bins = 5; 
    int histSize[] = { h_bins}; 
    float h_ranges[] = { 0, 180 };

    const float* ranges[] = { h_ranges };
    int channels[] = { 0 };

    MatND hist_input;
    calcHist( &hsv_input, 1, channels, Mat(), hist_input, 2, histSize, ranges, true, false );
    normalize( hist_input, hist_input, 0, 1, NORM_MINMAX, -1, Mat() );
```

But i am getting the following error:
**OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (s >= 0) in setSize**

Answer (score 2):

I should have used the following code:

```
 calcHist( &hsv_input, 1, channels, Mat(), hist_input, 1, histSize, ranges, true, false );
```